# MVC project for IIS hosting when you don't use controllers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, asp.net-web-api

I created a console application that is using Code First Entity Framework and WebApi, navigation part I want to do on front end, with a javascript framework. I took this approach because I haven't needed MVC controllers.

Now I'm working on authentication and also was searching for a way to host it in IIS, because I was advised to do that instead of selfhosting.

My question is, should I make an MVC project and move existing code to it even  if I don't use MVC controllers or how should I proceed if I need token Authentication and hosting in IIS?

Comment: If you are using WebAPI, you are fine with not using MVC project. Your javascript framework should be able to communicate with API and  in web api, you can have token based authentication via Owin.

Comment: @Akash KC, Okay so I could wire authentification to web api. But how to host console application in IIS ? I was searching for a better approach. Thanks

Comment: you can't host a console application in IIS - it's a console application, not a web application. You can (I believe, I haven't done it) include Web API controllers within a non-web application using OWIN and self-hosting, but that doesn't allow you to host in IIS. Why were you "advised to do that instead of self hosting"? What was the reason exactly? If you want to host an application in IIS, it has to be an actual web application (i.e MVC, Web API, Web Forms, WCF service, Classic ASP application, static HTML pages - one of those)

Comment: Move the code from your `Console` app to a `Web API` project. It won't have a `MVC` UI part, but you will have the possibility to host it (either self-hosted or IIS)

Comment: Self hosted Web API also supports authentication, so you don't really need IIS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services Several examples of token based authentication are listed, while you should be able to implement your own.